# Docpad on windows fails to run after following install instructions

Tags: windows, node.js, docpad

I'm having problems getting Docpad to run on Windows.

I did the following, as suggested here: http://docpad.org/docs/install

1. Installed the latest version of Node (.10.4)
2. npm install -g docpad@6.30
3. Then typed "docpad run" in an empty directory

It simply dumps the node help message:

```
Usage: node [options] [ -e script | script.js ] [arguments] 
   node debug script.js [arguments]
```

(etc)

Comment: We will need more information. DocPad each major and minor release of DocPad is tested on Windows XP and Windows 8 with the latest version of node. Can you post more information about your environment, or anything else that could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but will take a shot at helping. From your github comments,  it sounds like you're experienced with docpad and node and maybe just getting started testing on Windows Platform.

Running Windows 8, Node .10.4, npm 1.2.18, Docpad 6.30.3, I just tested this morning in empty directory and it went smooth.

First, I've been using `npm install -g docpad` rather than specifying version.

Are you successful using express with `npm install -g express` and `express testapp`? I've used this to help diagnose if it is a docpad issue or something related to node/path/environment vars (or just mix express into the equation).

As for environment, does your path include node `C:\Progra~1\nodejs` and git executable `C:\Progra~2\Git\bin`?

For some of the node module build tasks, I've found they want Windows build tools that are included with [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516.aspx) or whatever version you need.

I hope you get it working.